# Hyperledger: peer keep on thowing "Membership view has changed. peers went online/offline" errors

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We have one hyperledger setup(lets say N1) with 2 orgs(org1 & community-koinearth). Each Org has 2 peers(peer1. as anchor peer & peer2. as worker peer). In this setup we also have orderer service with 3 orderer with kafka. All the anchor peers and orderers are attached to their respective NLB. This setup is working completly fine.

Now we have setup another hyperledger infra(Let's say N2) with 1 org and 1 peer and basically trying to join the earlier network. Initially joiner peer successfully joined the N1. All the blocks were synced with no issues. After some time when we started to installed the chaincode then suddenly we started seeing peer online/offline messages on the joiner peer. We also noticed anchor peer of N1 is working fine and not throwing any error but worker peers of the network N1 are trying to contact the joiner org peer of network N2(This is strange. As per my knowledge only anchor peers talks to each other).

Below is the error logs from joiner org peer:

```
2019-12-23 12:42:28.572 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO ad30d Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051 ]] , current view:  [[peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051 ] [xxx-xxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:7051 ] [xxx-xxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:7051 ]]
2019-12-23 12:42:30.503 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad30e Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:30.503 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad30f Entering [d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81]
2019-12-23 12:42:30.503 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad310 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:30.503 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad311 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:30.511 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad312 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:32.474 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad313 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:32.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad314 Entering [d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81]
2019-12-23 12:42:32.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad315 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:32.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad316 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:33.512 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad317 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:33.512 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad318 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:33.512 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad319 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:33.512 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad31a Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:33.572 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO ad31b Membership view has changed. peers went offline:  [[peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051 ]] , current view:  [[xxx-xxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:7051 ] [xxx-xxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:7051 ]]
2019-12-23 12:42:35.474 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad31c Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:35.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad31d Entering [d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81]
2019-12-23 12:42:35.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad31e Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:35.474 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad31f Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:35.474 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad320 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:35.475 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad321 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:37.513 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad322 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:38.475 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad323 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:38.475 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad324 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:38.475 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad325 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:38.475 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad326 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:40.469 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad327 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:40.469 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad328 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:40.469 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad329 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:40.469 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad32a Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:40.514 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad32b Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:40.514 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad32c Entering [d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81]
2019-12-23 12:42:40.514 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad32d Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:40.514 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad32e Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:41.476 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad32f Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:42.499 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad330 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:43.470 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad331 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:43.470 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad332 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:43.470 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad333 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:43.470 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad334 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:45.501 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad335 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:45.501 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad336 Entering [d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81]
2019-12-23 12:42:45.501 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad337 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:45.501 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad338 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:45.516 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad339 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:45.516 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad33a Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:45.516 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad33b Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:45.516 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad33c Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:46.471 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad33d Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:47.503 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad33e Failed obtaining connection for peer2-community-koinearth.community-koinearth:7051, PKIid:d668cdb388896d68e8092fe38b6588c7e71d7c8d99e3c9de7ae7e63d58e39e81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:48.129 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad33f Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:48.129 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad340 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:48.129 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad341 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:48.129 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad342 Exiting
2019-12-23 12:42:48.517 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN ad343 Failed obtaining connection for peer2-org1.org1:7051, PKIid:81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b reason: context deadline exceeded
2019-12-23 12:42:48.517 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad344 Entering [81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b]
2019-12-23 12:42:48.517 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad345 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer2-org1.org1:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 81f6fac2aa059963f5dd5d11d71dfa2269f047c8796deff268f312a68c16c60b, Metadata: 
2019-12-23 12:42:48.517 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN ad346 Exiting
```

We are using hyperledger fabric 1.4.

Can anyone please help us resolving this issue? Let me know if any more info is required?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "As per my knowledge only anchor peers talks to each other"

No, all peers talk to all other peers in the same channel.

Comment: @yacovm worker peers(peer2.org1.org1) does not have external enpoint defined. only anchor peers have external endpoints. This is the secondary issue. The main issue is why peers are going online and offline.

Comment: Are you using the latest Fabric 1.4.x ?

Comment: @yacovm we are using fabric 1.4

Answer (score 0):

If you have peers that you don't want to communicate to peers in other organizations then don't put an [external endpoint](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L162) in these peers.

In other words, if a peer has an external endpoint defined, it should be routable from the entire network.

what I guess happens is that your anchor peers disseminate membership information of peers that are not routable from the entire network, and because of this - the other peers try to connect to them and fail.

> As per my knowledge only anchor peers talks to each other).

No, all peers can potentially talk to all other peers.

Comment: Hi @yacovm, we too faced something similar issue as above. In our case all the peers are open to talk to each other. Yet, on adding a new peer node in the same organization, when the new peer node has synced up, the online/offline WARN messages keep flooding the logs.